# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets missing

Tags: msbuild

I am installing a build agent on a virtual machine (using GoCD) and my goal is trying to keep it as light as possible, i.e., installing only MSBuild and avoid installing visual studio. 
One of my projects uses OfficeTools and when compiling the build I get the following error:

> C:\GoAgent1\pipelines\ProjectRepo\Office\MyProject.Office.Excel2007.UnderwritingNotes\MyProject.Office.Excel2007.UnderwritingNotes.csproj(365,3):
>   error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets"
>   was not found.  Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets doesn't exist! 
For that I will need to install "Office Tools for Visual Studio" which depends on Visual Studio (in this case VS2015 or 14.0).

One solution is copying this folder from my development machine but is sounds a bit messy!
So I was wondering if there are standalone versions that I can plug into MSBuild without installing Visual Studio. Any suggestion?